# Array of structs - How to create them correctly

Tags: c, struct

I'm learning about structs and memory allocation.

One of the things i found out by studying was that there is not a way to see if a block of memory was allocated correctly.

I think it's working properly, but i was getting ready to read about linked lists and got all confused again.

**I ask this, because on linked lists, i have seen:**

```
typedef LIST* Lint;

int main(){
    Lint *lint;
}
```

**and by defining the type of class like this on my code:**

```
typedef CLASS* t;

int main(){
    t class; // WITHOUT THE * BEFORE class
}
```

it worked! I thought it would be ok, to give the definition like this. To me makes sense, the class is now a pointer to a type (type ie. CLASS);

**So, am i on the right track or this working was pure luck?**

The code structure sucks, but i'm still learning :)

```
typedef struct student {
    char    name[50];
    int     grade;
} TURMA;

typedef CLASS* t;

void showS(struct student i){
    printf("Name of Student: %s \n Grade of Student: %d\n", i.name, i.grade);
}

void insert(struct student *i,int k){
    char n[100]; int q=0;
    printf("Define name of student %d\n", k+1); scanf("%s", n);
    printf("Define the grade of %s\n", n); scanf("%d", &q);
    strcpy(i->name,n);
    i->grade = q;
}


int main()
{
    t class;
    int total,plus,i;
    printf("Define number of total students: \n"); scanf("%d", &total);
    class = (struct student*) malloc(total*(sizeof(CLASS)));

    for(i=0; i<total; i++){
        insert(&class[i], i);
    }
    printf("\n\nThis is the complete class: \n");
    for(i=0; i<total; i++){
        showS(class[i]);
    }

    printf("(Total size after malloc: %lu) Add more students (Int)\n",sizeof(*turma)); scanf("%d", &plus);
    class = realloc(class, plus*sizeof(CLASS));
    free(class);

    printf("(Total size after malloc: %lu)", sizeof(*class));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if malloc fails, it returns a null pointer

Comment: Don't cast malloc: `class = malloc(total*(sizeof(CLASS)));` is all that is needed. (presuming `CLASS` is correct.). Also parenthesis are only needed when using `sizeof` with a data `type` (e.g. `sizeof (int)`), not when taking the size of a variable. `sizeof(*class)` can be simply `sizeof *class`

Comment: Why do they use `Lint *lint` instead of `Lint lint` ? Notice my `t class`, should it be `t *class`? This last option would make the pointer *class a pointer to a struct student* right?

Comment: No because `typedef CLASS* t` makes `t` an alias for `class*` (i.e. a pointer to `class`)

Comment: @skills Well, you have issues, but the `typedef Lint` allows creating a pointer of type `Lint` to point to the next node in the linked list. (e.g. `Lint *lint;`). However, you will never get to that point unless you define what `CLASS` is. You are trying to create a `typedef` for `t` from an uknown type. We need more of your code. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: The question is what? I do not see how the title corresponds to the code you show. Also the code does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really hard to tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish. I looks like you are trying to create a singly-linked-list out of `struct student` with a `typedef` of `struct student` to `TURMA`. That's about where the useful information ends. Attempting to declare `typedef CLASS* t;` makes no sense. The compiler doesn't know what `CLASS` is. Guessing what you were attempting, the following is what flows from your code.

**note:** I added one function `flush_stdin` to empty `stdin` so you wouldn't have pesky `newline` characters left in the buffer. I also changed the `scanf` format string to prevent leaving newlines following your reading of character strings. Take a look below, and I'll look at your latest additions.

Also note in your code, you cannot `free (class);` then expect to take `sizeof(*class))` -- that is undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN 100

typedef struct student {
    char    name[50];
    int     grade;
} TURMA;

typedef TURMA* t;

void flush_stdin () 
{
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

void showS (TURMA i)
{
    printf("Name of Student: %s \n Grade of Student: %d\n", i.name, i.grade);
}

void insert (t i, int k)
{
    char n[MAXN] = {0}; int q=0;

    printf("Define name of student %d\n", k+1); scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", n);
    printf("Define the grade of %s\n", n); scanf("%d", &q); flush_stdin();

    strcpy(i->name,n);
    i->grade = q;
}


int main()
{
    t class;
    int total,plus,i;

    printf("Define number of total students: \n"); scanf("%d", &total); flush_stdin();
    class = malloc (total * sizeof *class);
    if (!class) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i=0; i<total; i++){
        insert (&class[i], i);
    }

    printf("\n\nThis is the complete class: \n");
    for (i=0; i<total; i++){
        showS (class[i]);
    }

    printf("(Total size after malloc: %lu) Add more students (Int)\n", sizeof *class * total); 
    scanf("%d", &plus); flush_stdin();

    TURMA *turma = realloc (class, plus * sizeof *turma);
    if (!turma) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free (class);

    printf("(Total size after realloc: %lu)\n", sizeof *turma * (total + plus));

    free (turma);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/llclass
Define number of total students:
2
Define name of student 1
John James
Define the grade of John James
8
Define name of student 2
Jill James
Define the grade of Jill James
9


This is the complete class:
Name of Student: John James
 Grade of Student: 8
Name of Student: Jill James
 Grade of Student: 9
(Total size after malloc: 112) Add more students (Int)
2
(Total size after realloc: 224)
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights David, the code was already working, the reason on why it didn't compile is because i write my code in portuguese, and i've tried to translate all the terms to english before publishing here. 
But it was nice to see the changes you've made, makes much more sense now. Thank you very much.